# Have 2 queries and wondering if they can be combined

Tags: php, mysql

So i have 2 queries, I am trying to run one inside of a loop (unsuccessfully), but I'm thinking there might be a possibility that I can combine the 2 of them.

Table **profile_posts** 
*ID*
*post_title*
*post_body*
*user_id*
*post_date*

Table **profile_posts_likes**
*ID*
*likes*
*user_like_id*
*post_id*

```
$baseURL = 'Data.php'; //Grab page for pagination
$id = $_GET['id'];  //Grab id from link
$limit = 10;        //Limit returns to 10

//Select statement that grabs results from profile_posts table
$postQuery = "SELECT * FROM profile_posts WHERE user_id = :id ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $limit"; //First Query
// Count of all records 
$rowCount = countRecords($conn, $id);

// Initialize pagination class 
$paginationConfig = array( 
    'postID' => $id,
    'baseURL' => $baseURL, 
    'totalRows' => $rowCount, 
    'perPage' => $limit, 
    'contentDiv' => 'postContent', 
    'link_func' => 'searchFilterProfile' 
); 
$pagination =  new Pagination($paginationConfig);
$profilePost = $conn->prepare($postQuery);
$profilePost->bindParam(":id", $id);
$profilePost->execute();
if($profilePost->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($postDisplay as $row){
        $likeQuery = "SELECT id, COUNT(likes) as likeCount, user_Like_id, post_id FROM profile_posts_likes WHERE post_id = :postID";   //Second Query
        $likeQuery = $conn->prepare($likeQuery);
        $likeQuery->bindParam(":postID", $row['id']);  //Grab id from first query
        $likeQuery->execute();
        $postlikeQuery = $likeQuery->fetchAll();        
        if($likeQuery->rowCount() > 0){
            //Display like buttons, when user clicks "Like" button, send data through Ajax 
            //and update page with "Liked"
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is displays the posts on the users profile page, and then when a user views their page, they can 'Like' the post or 'unlike it'...Using Ajax to update page

Now is there a way that I can combine those 2 queries together instead of running one inside of the loop. I tried tossing a WHERE EXISTS in there to combine the Select statements, but no luck.
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share sample data and required result from the sample.

Comment: Ok, thats what I was wondering. So would it be ideal to run the one query inside of the loop. I'm sure that will slow things down quite a bit

Comment: @PHPFromTheBack You can have a column like numOfLikes in profile_posts table also. You can have a Trigger to update the numOfLikes whenever there is an Insert/Delete in profile_posts_likes table. Refer https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Comment: @Indra Kumar S That would work, but I was wanting the ability to display to the user if they have liked that post or not. So that they can "unlike" it later

Comment: Your query will become very slow when your profile_posts_likes table grows big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may express your query using a join:

```sql
SELECT ppl.id, ppl.user_Like_id, ppl.post_id
FROM profile_posts_likes ppl
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM profile_posts
    WHERE user_id = :id
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT $limit
) pp
    ON pp.id = ppl.post_id;
```

Selecting `COUNT` in the second query makes no sense, as you are not using `GROUP BY`.